# unescape_javascript() vs Coffeescript triple quotes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I've recently started using CoffeeScript's triple quote syntax for escaping html within JavaScript rather than RoR's `escape_javascript()`. But I was wondering if there were any major differences between the two that I should know about before switching.

Are there any benefits of one over the other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Triple quotes in CoffeeScript don't escape anything, they just handle interpolation, strip off some leading whitespace, and convert embedded newlines to `\n`; of course, `escape_javascript` doesn't do anything with HTML either. For example:

```
s = """
    <p>
        Pancakes & stuff!
        'single quotes'
        "double quotes"
    </p>
"""
```

becomes:

```
var s;
s = "<p>\n    Pancakes & stuff!\n    'single quotes'\n    \"double quotes\"\n</p>";
```

Single quotes have no meaning inside double quoted strings so CoffeeScript does nothing with them, double quotes are escaped though. But, an embedded triple quote will be interpreted as the end of the triple quoted string so, if your ERB came before your CoffeeScript to JavaScript translation, you could run into some trouble.

I would recommend against dropping `escape_javascript` in favor of throwing raw strings into CoffeeScript triple-quoted strings. If you really want to use triple-quoted strings then you'd do both:

```
s = """<%=j @s %>"""
```

but that would be a pointless use of `"""` since `"""` and [`escape_javascript`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/JavaScriptHelper.html#method-i-escape_javascript) do pretty much the same thing (except that `"""` will be confused by an embedded `"""` of course).

Comment: I didn't think to check Ampersands and similar characters. Is `j` an alias for `escape_javascript`?

Comment: @mcmullins: Yes, `j` is an alias for `escape_javascript`.

Comment: After thinking about it. I never needed to worry about escaping html in the first place. Most of the time it is either escaped when I write it, or escaped before I store it in the db. 

I don't know of too many cases where I would run into `"""` in html so I'm not too worried about that. The `j()` alias is great to know though. I still kinda wunna lean towards triple quotes simply because erb feels dirty to me.

Comment: @mcmullins: I can think of a case where you'd have `"""` in your HTML: if I was feeling mischievous while entering text for your application :)

Comment: Well the good news is the current app I'm working on is CMS only (no public editing), so for now I don't need to go worrying about changing the rewriting all my coffeescript. But for future apps, I'll definitely take this into consideration as a security hole.